# How to pass json image data to collection view pinterest style in swift

Tags: swift, swift2, uicollectionview, pinterest

Am developing a app using swift 2.2 in my app am using collection view with pinterest style so that am followed a method: https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout.

Am getting a data from the server which contains image that is

```
{"success":1,"error":0,"subcategory_value":"true","ad_count":126,"subcategory":[{"category id":"10","subcategory id":"37","subcategoryname":"Cars","image":"14720209352.jpg","link":"cars","id":"2628","advertising_id":"0002628","adtitle":"Toyota Corolla H5 1.8e make Year 2006 (petrol)","adtype":"1","specification":"","images":"toyota-corolla-h5-18e-make-year-2006-petrol-nm100370002628-14846608450.png,toyota-corolla-h5-18e-make-year-2006-petrol-nm100370002628-14846608461.png,toyota-corolla-h5-18e-make-year-2006-petrol-nm100370002628-14846608462.png,toyota-corolla-h5-18e-make-year-2006-petrol-nm100370002628-14846608463.png,toyota-corolla-h5-18e-make-year-2006-petrol-nm100370002628-14846608474.png","originalprice":"350000","offerprice":"0","contactno":"9840673154","address":"Tambaram, Chennai, Tamil Nadu, India","country":"India","state":"Tamil Nadu","districtname":"Chennai","postcode":"","subcategory_icon":"fa-id-badge"}]}
```

The key value :images" contains the image i want to pass that image to my collection view

code in my view controller:

```
import UIKit 
import CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout 
import SDWebImage
  class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,CHTCollectionViewDelegateWaterfallLayout,UITabBarDelegate,UISearchBarDelegate,UIToolbarDelegate {


var arrDict = NSMutableArray()


@IBOutlet var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
self.myCollectionView.dataSource  = self
self.myCollectionView.delegate = self
setupCollectionView()
jsonParsingFromURL()
}
```

func setupCollectionView(){

```
// Create a waterfall layout
let layout = CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout()

// Change individual layout attributes for the spacing between cells
layout.minimumColumnSpacing = 4.0
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 4.0

// Collection view attributes
self.myCollectionView.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth]
self.myCollectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
self.myCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
// Add the waterfall layout to your collection view
self.myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

}

```
 func jsonParsingFromURL () {
let url = NSURL(string: myapiKey + "category.com")
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {(response, data, error) in
    self.startParsing(data!)
}
```

}

```
func startParsing(data :NSData)
```

{

```
  let dict: NSDictionary!=(try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as! NSDictionary
for i in 0  ..< (dict.valueForKey("subcategory") as! NSArray).count
{
    arrDict.addObject((dict.valueForKey("subcategory") as! NSArray) .objectAtIndex(i))
}
myCollectionView.reloadData()
```

}

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("PinterestCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

let URL_API_HOST2:String = "https://www.something.com/"
let images = arrDict[indexPath.row].valueForKey("images") as! NSString
let parts = images.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
let firstImage = parts[0]
 cell.image.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: URL_API_HOST2 + (firstImage as String)))
return cell
```

}

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
```

}

help me to pass that image to the collection view

Comment: Check this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/107439/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest

Comment: that one is different according to my method..is there any possible in my way to do